# Can't get my async function to properly work

Tags: python, python-3.x, websocket, jupyter-notebook, python-asyncio

I'm trying to build a script based on data provided by a WebSocket, but I have a tricky problem I can't solve. I have two cells.

The first one:

```
msg = ''

stream = {}

async def call_api(msg):
    async with websockets.connect('wss://www.bitmex.com/realtime?subscribe=quote:XBTUSD,quote:ETHU19') as websocket:
        await websocket.send(msg)
        while websocket.open:
            response = await websocket.recv()
            response = json.loads(response)

            if 'data' in list(response.keys()):

                response = response['data']

                for n in range(len(response)):

                    symbol = response[n]['symbol']

                    stream[symbol] = response[n]['askPrice']


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.create_task(call_api(msg))
```

The second one:

```
stream['XBTUSD']
```

If I run the first cell in Jupyter Notebook and then run the second cell manually afterward, python will print the correct value. But if I press the "restart the current kernel and re-execute the whole notebook" button I get the error `KeyError: 'XBTUSD'` at the second cell. This error also happens when I run the script with the python shell.

I can't understand the difference in behavior between these two executions.

Comment: Can you check the type of `stream['XBTUSD']` when the cells are run immediately after each other? If it's a coroutine you'll need to await it.

Comment: @HarryMW `stream['XBTUSD']` doesnt exist when I run imediately. 
What I think happened is that when no cells are running in jupyter it automatically keep hearing the websocket, but when cells are running it only receives the first message from the websocket, witch is an introductory message, and doesn't include information about XBTUSD. I think you are right, I need to await it. Am not sure how to do it though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you created an asyncio task in the first cell but did *not* wait for it to finish. `loop.create_task()` immediately returns and let the event loop to continue execution of the created task in background as long as the event loop is alive. (In this case, the event loop keeps running while your notebook kernel is running.) Therefore, `loop.create_task()` makes your Jupyter notebook to think that the first cell is done immediately.

Note that Jupyter notebook itself also works asynchronously against the kernel process, so if you run the second cell after the first cell too quickly (e.g., using "restart the current kernel and re-execute the whole notebook" instead of manually clicking the Run button), the first cell's asyncio task would not finish before the second cell's execution starts.

To ensure the first cell to actually finish the task before reporting that the cell's execution has finished, use `run_until_complete()` instead of `create_task()`:

```
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(call_api(msg))
```

or, to get additional control over your task with a reference to it:

```
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
t = loop.create_task(call_api(msg))
loop.run_until_complete(t)
```

If you want to keep the task running in background for an indefinite time, you need a different approach.

- Don't use Jupyter notebook and write a daemonized process to continuously fetch and process websocket messages. Jupyter does not provide any means to keep track of background asyncio tasks in the kernel process and execute cells by event triggers from such background tasks. Jupyter notebook is simply not a tool for such patterns.
- To decouple websocket message receiver and the processing routines, use an intermediate queue. If both sides run in the same process and the same event loop, you may use `asyncio.Queue`. If the processing happens in a different thread using synchronous codes, you could try out [`janus`](https://github.com/aio-libs/janus). If the processing happens in a different process, use `multiprocessing.Queue` or some other IPC mechanisms.